# Controle de edição de perguntas em tempo real

Tags: suporte, edição, edições-sugeridas

Já estou no SOpt há algum tempo e tem uma funcionalidade que percebi melhor esses dias e me deixou intrigado: a edição em andamento.

Percebi que se alguém já está editando uma resposta ou pergunta, a opção <kbd>editar</kbd> fica desativada (semelhante a respostas wiki).
Como este recurso funciona (teoricamente) para ser aplicado a um fórum por exemplo?

Comment: Você quer saber como funciona esse recurso no [pt.so] ou você quer ajuda para implementar esse recurso em um projeto seu?

Comment: @Math apenas entender como funciona mesmo, pode ser de forma teorica, sem código.

Comment: Isto não será pergunta para o http://pt.stackoverflow.com @Math?

Comment: @JorgeB. Talvez. Acho meio cabível nos dois. Por um lado é uma pergunta de programação, por outro é uma pergunta especificamente sobre uma função do site, que só poderia ser adequadamente respondida (se ele quiser saber como *nós* implementamos) por alguém da empresa

Comment: @Jorge, aparentemente, é uma "pesquisa prévia" para investigar a programação envolvida no assunto, jeje

Answer (score 10):

As edições não são bloqueadas enquanto outra pessoa está editando. O que acontece é o seguinte:

Se uma edição acontece enquanto outra está sendo feita, nós tentamos um merge automático das duas - mais ou menos da mesma forma como se resolve um merge conflict em código. Se o conflito não puder ser resolvido, a última edição é rejeitada.

Quanto ao link de 'editar' desabilitado, isso só acontece quando há uma **sugestão de edição** na pergunta que ainda não foi aprovada. Quando isso acontece, não permitimos que outras edições sejam feitas justamente para que elas não entrem em conflito.

Comment: Então  a desativação do link não significa necessariamente que outra pessoa está editando a pergunta naquele instante, e sim, que a sugestão de edição está pendente?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Exatamente. Não tem nada que impeça 2 ou mais pessoas de editarem um post ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: "É bem menos impressionante do que parece..." not for me! :)

Comment: @gustavox nem para mim, eu já acho demais estar em uma pergunta e surgir a mensagem que tem resposta nova do nada, ou que a resposta que estou lendo foi atualizada, imagina um recurso desses hehe

Comment: @Gabe obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, o SOpt é bem mais sofisticado do que parece pelo visto.

Comment: @Diego, então, agora o negócio é saber o nome dessas técnicas e sair pesquisando/perguntando no SO(pt), é genial mesmo ;)

Comment: `resposta nova do nada, ou que a resposta que estou lendo foi atualizada` eu faço isso usando ajax e nodeJs (socket) mais especificamente é um recurso bem legal mesmo